# Check if any web application is working or not

Tags: javascript, html, http, websocket

Is there any way to check if my hosted website is working or not, i mean http request and web socket connection as well on that website/application on specific port using Javascript and if not, than report the same via email. This script has to be running on different server and reporting in every minute only if any of the service is down [http or ws].

Comment: Are you looking for 3rd party tool for monitoring?

Comment: Not really, but some customized hand written functions.

Comment: May be this http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/134838/any-website-monitoring-library-modules-to-use-in-my-website